# How to integrate SonarQube with SAP Hybris

Tags: sonarqube, sap-commerce-cloud

SAP Hybris Suite comes with integrated PMD Plugin and runs custom PMD Code rulesets.

The PMD Plugin is called through Hybris ANT build script.

But i would like to know if there is a way to integrate Hybris Suite with SonarQube

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your hybris version, there's an already existing `sonar` Ant task that will send the metrics to Sonar.

First go to your platform home:

```
cd $HYBRIS_HOME/hybris/bin/platform
```

Then, to initialize Ant correctly:

```
. ./setantenv.sh
```

Execute tests:

```
ant unittests
```

The send the results to Sonar:

```
ant sonar
```

Sonar Runner can be configured inside the platform in the `config/local.properties` file. For example:

```
sonar.java.source=8
sonar.projectName=Example
sonar.projectKey=example
sonar.exclusions=file:**/gensrc/**, **/ws/axis/*
sonar.login=secret
sonar.password=evenmoresecret
sonar.excludedExtensions=core,testweb,scripting,paymentstandard,mediaweb,maintenanceweb,deliveryzone,commons,processing,impex,validation,catalog,europe1,platformservices,workflow,hac,comments,advancedsavedquery,springintegrationlibs,ldap,hmc,virtualjdbc,cockpit,admincockpit,reportcockpit,platformhmc,productcockpit,customerreview,sapcoretest,sapcoreodata,sapcore,sapcorejco,sapcorejcorec,sapcorebol,advancedexport,backoffice,datahubbackoffice,mcc,wishlist,mediaconversion,solrfacetsearch,solrfacetsearchhmc,voucher,promotions,basecommerce,ticketsystem,cms2,cms2lib,btg,cmscockpit,btgcockpit,b2bcommerce,payment,commerceservices,b2bapprovalprocess,commercewebservicescommons,cscockpit,acceleratorservices,b2bacceleratorservices,acceleratorcms,commercefacades,acceleratorfacades,acceleratorstorefrontcommons,b2bacceleratorfacades,addonsupport,sapcoreaddon,captchaaddon,liveeditaddon,commercesearch,commercesearchhmc,commercesearchbackoffice,datahubadapter,sapcoreconfiguration,sapmodel,sapproductavailability,sapproductavailabilityhmc,b2bsapproductavailability,sappricingbol,sappricinghmc,sappricing,sappricingproductcarouseladdon,b2bsappricing,sapcustomerb2c,sapcustomerb2b,sapmodelhmc,saporderexchange,saporderexchangeb2b,sapcoreconfigurationhmc,sapproducthmc,sapcoreconfigurationbackoffice,multipaymentmode,amazonpay,codpayment,bspay,paypalservice
```

This is also the place you might want to configure the Sonar instance results need to be sent to.

Comment: In the `config/local.properties`. I've updated the above snippet to display it.

Comment: Hi Nicolas..so based on your comments, i should be able to add the Sonar.URL parameter to config/local.properties file..I would also like to know if Hybris has written any custom PMD rules..if yes, then how can i migrate these rules to the sonarqube instance.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, when I tried this ages ago, it tried to analyse all the Hybris out of the box extensions as well as my new custom ones. Is that still the case?
I ended up writing a really complicated custom ant task for analysing only my extensions...

Comment: Hi Kabadisha, can you tell me where did you configure the Sonar.URL. Is it in the config/local.properties file as mentioned by nicolas.

Comment: For me, its says Unable to execute Sonar - caused by Two modules have the same id: ''. Each module must have a unique id. I am not getting what module ids it is getting as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is Java code we're talking about you can easily "analyze" it with SonarQube. As far as "integrating" it goes, if you mean that you want to run the "custom PMD Code rulesets" via SonarQube, that's should be just a matter of installing the SonarQube PMD plugin and setting up the Quality Profile.

Answer (score 0):

The `sonar` target is deprecated. Instead you should use the `sonarcheck` target. This target by default scans all extensions added to the `localextensions.xml` file, but you may overwrite this list. All parameters may be configured by using the `local.properties` file or by passing them by the system properties (parameters prefixed with `-D`).

Let's say you have 4 extensions in the `bin/modules/custom` directory. They are named `ext1`, `ext2`, `ext3` and `ext4`. Bellow are steps which should be executed to perform SonarScanner analysis with a test code coverage.

#### Build Software

SonarScanner requires the project to be built (binary files are required).

1. configure Ant

   ```
   cd ${HYBRIS_HOME}/hybris/bin/platform
   . ./setantenv.sh
   ```
2. create `localextensions.xml`

   ```
   ant extensionsxml \
         -Dplatform.extensionsgen.filename=${HYBRIS_HOME}/hybris/config/localextensions.xml \
         -Dplatform.extensions=ext1,ext2,ext3,ext4
   ```
3. build software

   ```
   ant all
   ```

#### Execute Tests (+JaCoCo)

The SAP Hybris suite provides two tasks to execute tests:

- alltests - tests for classes in the main classpath
- allwebtests - tests for classes in the web context

Both must be executed with additional parameters to generate test code coverage report.

1. download JaCoCo agent

   ```
   cd /tmp
   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.6/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.6-runtime.jar -O jacocoAgent.jar
   cd ${HYBRIS_HOME}/hybris/bin/platform
   ```
2. execute `alltests`

   ```
   ant alltests \
         -Dtestclasses.extensions=ext1,ext2,ext3,ext4 \
         -Dtestclasses.reportdir=/tmp/alltests \
         -Dstandalone.javaoptions="-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR -javaagent:/tmp/jacocoAgent.jar=destfile=/tmp/jacocoAlltests.exec"
   ```

   The `java.locale.providers` parameter is required to not break tests which uses non ASCII characters in the `impex` files. It is only needed when the JaCoCo agent is added.
3. Execute `allwebtests`

   ```
   ant allwebtests \
         -Dtestclasses.extensions=ext1,ext2,ext3,ext4 \
         -Dtestclasses.reportdir=/tmp/allwebtests \
         -Dstandalone.javaoptions="-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR -javaagent:/tmp/jacocoAgent.jar=destfile=/tmp/jacocoAllwebtests.exec"
   ```

When all tests are done we have to convert the JaCoCo `exec` files to the XML format.

1. download JaCoCo cli

   ```
   cd /tmp
   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.cli/0.8.6/org.jacoco.cli-0.8.6-nodeps.jar -O jacocoCli.jar
   cd ${HYBRIS_HOME}/hybris/bin/platform
   ```
2. create XML report

   ```
   java -jar /tmp/jacocoCli.jar report \
          /tmp/jacocoAlltests.exec \
          /tmp/jacocoAllwebtests.exec \
          --classfiles ${HYBRIS_HOME}/hybris/bin/modules/custom/ext1 \
          --classfiles ${HYBRIS_HOME}/hybris/bin/modules/custom/ext2 \
          --classfiles ${HYBRIS_HOME}/hybris/bin/modules/custom/ext3 \
          --classfiles ${HYBRIS_HOME}/hybris/bin/modules/custom/ext4 \
          --xml /tmp/jacocoTestReport.xml
   ```

#### Execute SonarScanner

There are a few parameters which should be set:

- `sonar.host.url` - the SonarQube/SonarCloud server URL
- `sonar.login` - the user's token used to authorize to the server
- `sonar.projectKey` - the project identifier
- `sonar.projectName` - the project display name
- `sonar.projectVersion` - the project version
- `sonar.java.source` - the Java version required to run the software (required only for versions older than 2105)
- `sonar.extensions` - the extensions which should be analyzed (required only for versions older than 2105)
- `sonar.junit.reportPaths` - the paths to the test results
- `sonar.test.exclusions` - the tests which should be excluded by SonarScanner
- `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths` - the path to the JaCoCo XML report

```
ant sonarcheck
      -Dsonar.host.url=https://example.org/ \
      -Dsonar.login=1234567890abcdefghijk \
      -Dsonar.projectKey=my.company:custom-extensions \
      -Dsonar.projectName="Custom Extensions" \
      -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT \
      -Dsonar.java.source=11 \
      -Dsonar.extensions=ext1,ext2,ext3,ext4 \
      -Dsonar.junit.reportPaths=/tmp/alltests,/tmp/allwebtests \
      -Dsonar.test.exclusions= \
      -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=/tmp/jacocoTestReport.xml
```